# Instagram API Secure Request

Tags: php, curl, instagram, instagram-api, get-request

I have the following secure request code:

```
$apiCall = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/liked?sig='.$sig.'&access_token='.$token;

$request = curl_init();
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_URL, $apiCall);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$jsonData2 = curl_exec($request);
curl_close($request);

var_dump($jsonData2);
```

According to Instagram Documentation, it works because I get the following response:

> {"pagination": {}, "meta": {"code": 200}, "data": []}

App is in Sandbox, but I am querying about a sandbox user (self). How can I see the real info? I mean, the structure with the likes data? Am I missing headers or something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the endpoint to: "/users/self/media/recent" and return the expected response.

So, in sandbox, you can only see media and details OF the sandbox user. Even the interactions of this user in other accounts and media are invisible in sandbox mode.